# Datedif function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a quick question. Is there any solution to use DATEDIF function in VBA. It's a hidden function in Excel. I'm not asking about DATEDIFF function with two 'F' at the end.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to use `DateDif` instead of `DateDiff`? They do the same thing...

Comment: Aren't they? If they was, I wouldn't ask question like this one :(

Comment: Yes, they are. The syntax is different, but they do the same thing. So again, why do you want to use [DateDif](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datedif.php) instead of [DateDiff](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php)?

Comment: I want to use it, to count difference between two dates in days. If between two days are 2 months which means 60 or 61 days in my case, I have to increment certain value.

Comment: @Matt_DontKnow To count the difference between two dates in days, merely subtract one from the other.

Comment: Okey, for example we have two different dates. First one is "2016-02-14" and the second one is "2016-03-10". DateDif function will return 0, which is appropriate result but DateDiff will return 1 instead of 0. DATEDIF("2016-02-14"; "2016-03-10";"ym") and vba DATEDIFF("m","2016-02-14", "2016-03-10")

Comment: So they cant' be the same!

Comment: You wrote you wanted the days between dates, not the months between dates.  Which is it?

Comment: @Matt_DontKnow In VBA, to subtract those two dates and get the result in days, merely:  `#2016-03-10# - #2016-02-14#` --> 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Evaluate` method...

`Evaluate("DATEDIF(A1,A2,""Y"")")`

And yes, you can use variables...

```
Sub TestEvaluateWithVariables()

    Dim strVariable As String
    Dim dateStartDate As Date
    Dim dateEndDate As Date

    dateStartDate = #9/1/2002#
    dateEndDate = #11/30/2003#

    strVariable = "DATEDIF(""" & dateStartDate & """,""" & dateEndDate & """,""YD"")"

    Cells(3, 3) = Evaluate(strVariable)

End Sub
```

Comment: Bingo. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can i use it with variables?

Comment: Matt -- if this answer addresses your issue, you should mark it as correct so that future people with a similar question will identify this as the solution

Comment: I forgot about it. I've already marked it as correct answer. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly an answer, but seeing as it is too long for a comment and still somewhat relevant to your usage, I'll submit it.

> Okey, for example we have two different dates. First one is
>   "2016-02-14" and the second one is "2016-03-10". DateDif function will
>   return 0, which is appropriate result but DateDiff will return 1
>   instead of 0. DATEDIF("2016-02-14"; "2016-03-10";"ym") and vba
>   DATEDIFF("m","2016-02-14", "2016-03-10")

The reason `DateDiff` and `DateDif` gives you two different values in this usage seems to be because one of them calculates the full month difference and the other counts the offset of the months themselves without paying attention to the days.

`DateDiff`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx

> Similarly, the return value for DateInterval.Month is calculated
>   purely from the year and month parts of the arguments

`DateDif`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc767548.aspx

> "M" The number of complete months in the period.

I take from this that `DateDiff` returns the count of how far away the two months are from each other (February and March are always 1 month apart, because it doesn't care what day of the month you supplied) while `DateDif` seems to count the number of days to determine whether a "complete" month has been achieved or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Function DateDif(D1 As Date, D2 As Date, DDS$) As Integer
Dim DHi As Date, DLow As Date
Dim DifS$: DifS = "DATEDIF(" & Chr(34)
Dim dCom: dCom = Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34)
Dim DEnd: DEnd = Chr(34) & ")"
If D2 < D1 Then
    DateDif = Evaluate(DifS & D2 & dCom & D1 & dCom & DDS & DEnd)
Else
    DateDif = Evaluate(DifS & D1 & dCom & D2 & dCom & DDS & DEnd)
End If
```

End Function

' may be worth a play